# 2 pgfplots in tikzpicture are overlapping

Tags: pgfplots

In a previous work I did, I had a plot with two png images side by side and a small label such as (a) and (b) beside them like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\fontsize{14pt}{11pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[](a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{graphics/image1.png}};
    \node[below right] at (a.north west){\normalsize (a)};
    
    \node[right](b) at (a.east) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{graphics/image2.png}};
    \node[below right] at (b.north west){\normalsize (b)};
   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_fig}
\end{figure}
```

Now, I want the same with pgfplots and tried this

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[](a) at (0,0) {\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\import{graphics/}{figure1.pgf}}};
        \node[below right] at (a.north west){\normalsize (a)};
        
        \node[](b) at (a.east) {\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\import{graphics/}{figure2.pgf}}};
        \node[below right] at (b.north west){\normalsize (b)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

But unfortunately the two pictures overlap. How can I fix this?

This is how it looks with the png images:

[image]

And this is with the pgfplots. You can see they are overlapping.

[image]

Comment: not directly related but why `\fontsize{14pt}{11pt}` ? This does nothing unless you also apply `\selectfont` but then it would select a 14pt font on baselines 11pt apart which can not work and will produce very inconsistent baselines.

Comment: \resizebox is from \adjustbox, not pgfplots.  I can't find any trace of \import{graphics}, but it is definitely not part of pgfplots.  Unless you are in an axis environment, you are using normal tikz anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah sorry that is useless.

Comment: @JohnKormylo ok, so what should I then use instead?

Comment: First, what package defines \import and why are you using it when \includegraphics works fine?

Comment: @JohnKormylo \includegraphics does not work for me, because with `{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{graphics/figure1.pgf}};` I get the error `LaTeX Error: unknown graphics extension: pgf.`

Comment: And is use this import command `\usepackage{graphicx,svg,import}`

Comment: While there **is** such a thing as PGF graphics format, import shouldn't be able to decode it.  That it works at all means that it consists of LaTeX code, and you are running tikz inside tikz.

Comment: Ok, so \import is not the correct way and \includegraphics is not working. What else is there?

Comment: This would have been so much faster with an MWE we could use.

Comment: @JohnKormylo what is MWE?

Comment: Minimal Working Example - code we can copy and run as is.

Comment: Why can't you use my MWE? Just replace the figures with something on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I have no way to test this, but this is one way to put a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture.

```
\begin{figure}
    \sbox0{\import{graphics/}{figure1.pgf}}%
    \sbox1{\import{graphics/}{figure2.pgf}}%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[](a) at (0,0) {\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\usebox0}};
        \node[below right] at (a.north west){\normalsize (a)};
        
        \node[right](b) at (a.east) {\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\usebox1}};
        \node[below right] at (b.north west){\normalsize (b)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

---

The tikzscale package provides a pgf driver for `\includegraphics`.  I still can't test it without the files figure1 and figure2.  The saveboxes are probably not needed, since the pgf driver no doubt uses them.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\textwidth=6in

\begin{document}
    \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{graphics/figure1.pgf}}%
    \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{graphics/figure2.pgf}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[](a) at (0,0) {\usebox0};
        \node[below right] at (a.north west){\normalsize (a)};
        
        \node[right](b) at (a.east) {\usebox1};
        \node[below right] at (b.north west){\normalsize (b)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but the two figures are still overlapping

Comment: Well, you did specify putting the center of (b) over the right size of (a).

Comment: Ok, but then this is wrong, because I don't want that. I just don't know what I did wrong, that's why I wanted help.

Comment: Admittedly I should have caught that sooner, but putting tikzpictures inside tikzpictures is wrong.  Sometimes you can get away with it. but it is better to avoid it altogehter.

Comment: Ok, so there is no solution for my problem?

Comment: If you mean the overlap, that was easy.